# How can I retrieve value from firebase using Hashmap in a recyclerview?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

```
  private void FetchHistoryInformation() {
    
    String user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    DatabaseReference tripRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.RIDER_INFO_REFERENCE).child(user).child("Trips");
    query = tripRef.orderByChild("tripCount");

    options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<RiderModel>()
            .setLifecycleOwner(this)
            .setQuery(query, RiderModel.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RiderModel, CompletedTripAdapter>(options) {

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CompletedTripAdapter holder, int position,
                                        @NonNull final RiderModel model) {

            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                        for (DataSnapshot itemSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            HashMap<String, Object> hasmap = new HashMap<>();

                            String pickup = itemSnapshot.child("pickupLocation").getValue(String.class);
                            String destination = itemSnapshot.child("destination").getValue(String.class);
                            long time = itemSnapshot.child("timeStamp").getValue(Long.class);

                            arrayList.add(hasmap);

                            holder.txt_pickup.setText(pickup);

                            holder.txt_destination.setText(destination);

                            holder.txt_trip_status.setText(R.string.status_complete);

                            holder.txt_trip_date.setText(UserUtils.getDate(time));

                            holder.setItemClickListerner(new IRecyclerClickListerner() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClickListerner(View view, int pos) {
                                    //
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), adapter.getRef(position).getKey(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TripHistorySinglePage.class);

                                    intent.putExtra("destination", destination);
                                    startActivity(intent);

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            });
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public CompletedTripAdapter onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_completed_trips, parent, false);

            return new CompletedTripAdapter(view);
        }
    };
    recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();

}
```

[image]

Above is my firebase database structure, i am trying to get data from firebase db to firebaseRecyclerAdapter using Hashmap (i have not use model class to set and get data i have use hashmap to set data in a firebase database). But when i add data to my onBindView i get all items but with repeatedly last item informations. Check below result image

[image]

That item results information are repeatedly from the last item added in a firebase database.

Comment: What does your `RiderModel` look like?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i have riderModel class but i dont have any getter and setter with that information, i have used hashmap to put data to the firebase db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating things a bit in your code. If you don't want to use a custom model class, pass `into the`.

```
DatabaseReference tripRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.RIDER_INFO_REFERENCE).child(user).child("Trips");
query = tripRef.orderByChild("tripCount");

options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<DataSnapshot>()
        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
        .setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<DataSnapshot>() {
            public DataSnapshot parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                return snapshot;
            }
        })
        .build();

adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataSnapshot, CompletedTripAdapter>(options) {

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CompletedTripAdapter holder, int position,
                                    @NonNull final DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        String pickup = snapshot.child("pickupLocation").getValue(String.class);
        String destination = snapshot.child("destination").getValue(String.class);
        long time = snapshot.child("timeStamp").getValue(Long.class);

        holder.txt_pickup.setText(pickup);
        holder.txt_destination.setText(destination);
        holder.txt_trip_status.setText(R.string.status_complete);
        holder.txt_trip_date.setText(UserUtils.getDate(time));
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CompletedTripAdapter onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_completed_trips, parent, false);

        return new CompletedTripAdapter(view);
    }
};
recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.startListening();
```

The `new SnapshotParser<DataSnapshot>() {...}` in here is a simple parser that returns the `DataSnapshot` unparsed.

Comment: hello thank you for your respond but i dont understand on how to implement that function because when i try i get many errors and also i don't understand how you implement snapshot on this line :  public Snapshot parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot). thank you

Comment: That last one should've been `DataSnapshot` too. Fixed it in my answer now.

Comment: thanks it worked. but you should also edit your answer and replace all RiderModel with Datasnapshot. For future readers.

Comment: Hello sorry can you help me on how can i get a key on every items. because when i try a code like snapshot.getkey() i get key but every item has the same key. I need to get a different key for the items like that informations.  @frank-van-puffelen

Comment: It sounds like you're calling `getKey()` on the wrong object in that case, but it's hard to be sure without more context. I recommend posting a new question with its own [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok in a simple way, i have added a line  `String tripKey = snapshot.getKey()` in onBindViewHolder, for fetching key and it worked perfect , but i need that  `String tripKey` to be a global variable so that i can use it in another class to populate another database with the same keys. when i try that way it gives me the same key for both items(the last added item key).